# Primefaces overlayPanel Not rendering Column Header

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2

Column header *My Heading 1* for 1st column in datatable is not rendering in output.

Every thing else is working fine, both rendering conditions are working and printing elements as they are supposed to.I am using primefaces 5.0.

Below is my xhtml code. I have changed variable names for better understanding.

P.S I have tried with and without facet.

```
<p:overlayPanel 
    id="detailPanel"
    for="detailBtn"
    hideEffect="fade"
    dynamic="true">

    <p:dataTable 
        var="msg"
        value="#{bean}" 
        rows="5" 
        paginator="true">

        <p:column headerText="My Heading 1"
            rendered="#{renderedConditionForCol1}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="My Heading 1"/>
                </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.msisdnsCsv}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText=""
                  rendered="{renderedConditionForCol2}">

                <p:dataTable var="dept" value="#{bean.myList}">
                        <p:column headerText="Header Name">
                                  <h:outputText value="#{dept.name}" />
                        </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Comment: What is that `rendered="#{c}"` for on column one?

Comment: I have edited that, its just a rendered condition for column 1 and its working.

Comment: By working I mean it print rows when it should but not the header text

Comment: so removing the overlaypanel makes it work?

Comment: well i need overlaypanel, cant remove that. But i'll try just in case if thats the reason

Comment: @Kukeltje     I tried removing overlypanel , but that dosen't even print the first column